# How to best animate a UITableViewCell or UIButton to light up in red repitetly

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uitableview, uibutton

I want an `UITableViewCell` (-background) to shortly light up in red and return to the old appearance again. This is done during the life of an `NSTimer` which is giving the constant impulse to invoke the animation.

Right now I am using UIView's `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` method to first change the cells background color to red and then in the completion part to turn it gray again (the cell's background is gray). But this solution doesn't work smoothly for some reason.

QUESTION: **Thinking of *core animation*, how would I best do this kind of animation for (a) an `UITableVeiwCell` and (b) an `UIButton` ?**

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using an `NSTimer` to trigger the animation over and over again. Somehow it was giving the above described side effects. Now I am using the block animation available since `iOS4` which is working much smoother. You have to combine the `(UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse)` options to repeat the Animation:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:kDurationOfCellAnimation delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                 animations:^{
                     //this will be animated in and out
                     cell.backgroundColor = CELL_RECORDING_COLOR;

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){

                     cell.backgroundColor = TABLEVIEW_BACKGROUND_COLOR;

                 }];
```

The only side effect I experienced was that the animation stops when the cell goes off screen, which wasn't the case with the `NSTimer`.

Answer (score 1):

animateWithDuration is a UIView wrapper for core animation, but you could try doing it a little lower level and see if there is a change.
To do an explicit CA transaction on a CALayer do something like:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[CATransaction setAnimationTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut]];
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{ //Your completion block }];

view.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

[CATransaction commit];
```

Where view is the control in question. For a UIButton that would just be the button itself, for UITableViewCell it would depend on whether the table was grouped or not or if you are using a custom UITableViewCell. A grouped table cell adds a backgroundview property.

Comment: I am using a custom UITableViewCell. I updated my question with more details and the code. May you see something going wrong?

Comment: It seems to have lost its ability to animate the layer after the first go. Make sure you are on the main thread since this is a UI operation. The other issue I see is that the layer delegate may have changed for the table view cell. If thats the case you could try adding a new layer and just animating that since sometimes CA has an issue with the delegate of the top level layer. You can create a new layer with [CALayer layer] and add it to your layer just like you add a subview to a view. Create it with the same bounds and then run your animation on that maybe. Otherwise I am out of ideas....

Comment: It didn't change the weird behavior. Thanks a lot for your help.